# Extract different patterns of lat long date time float from 1 string and split it to variables

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, scanf, preg-split

I need a regex expert who can split this single string variable into multiple variables. Coming data from source having line break but not showing \n.
I will be very thankful.

```
$text_utf8_test = "lat:24.910717 lon:67.073710
speed:0.00
T:17/02/22 17:00
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=24.910717,67.073710&z=16
Pwr: ON Door: OFF ACC: OFF";
```

Expected PHP variables after spliting

```
echo $lat;
echo $long;
echo $speed;
echo $time;
echo $pwr;
echo $door;
echo $acc;
```

Expected Output Result

```
24.910717 /*This value can be vary due to dynamic update from location*/
67.073710
0.00 /*this can be from zero to 320*/
ON /*this can be ON or OFF*/
OFF /*this can be ON or OFF*/
OFF /*this can be ON or OFF*/
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try it at first yourself and show us your expressions. This site is not a code writing service.

Comment: will we see your efforts?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the wonderful help! specially @ventiseis I've done this myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text_utf8_test = "lat:24.910717 lon:67.073710
speed:0.00
T:17/02/22 17:59
http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=24.910717,67.073710&z=16
Pwr: ON Door: OFF ACC: OFF";
$phone_test = "88888888888";

echo $text_utf8_test;
preg_match('/([0-9.-]+).+?([0-9.-]+)/', $text_utf8_test, $matches); /*For lat long exclusively*/
//preg_match('/OFF/', $text_utf8_test, $test);
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $text_utf8_test); /*For spliting this whole string*/
preg_match('~speed:([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)~', $keywords[2], $speed ); /*For grabing speed*/
preg_match('/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/', $keywords[3].$keywords[4], $split_date_time ); /*For grabing date time*/
/*Spliting and combining date time into sql format*/
if(!empty($split_date_time[3])){
$date = $split_date_time[3].$split_date_time[2].$split_date_time[1];
echo "</br>";
$date_sanitized1 = strtotime($split_date_time[2]."/".$split_date_time[3]."/".$split_date_time[1]);
$date_sanitized2 = date('Y-m-d',$date_sanitized1);
$date_time = $date_sanitized2." ".$split_date_time[4].":".$split_date_time[5].":"."00.000" ;    
}

if((!empty($keywords[2])) && (!empty($keywords[8])) && (!empty($keywords[10])) && (!empty($keywords[12]))){
$speed=$speed[1];
$power=$keywords[8];
$door=$keywords[10];
$acc=$keywords[12];
}

$lat=$matches[1];
$long=$matches[2];


if ((!empty($lat)) && (!empty($long)) && (!empty($speed)) && (!empty($date_time))  && (!empty($power))  && (!empty($door))  && (!empty($acc)) ){
echo "</br>";
echo $lat;
echo "</br>";
echo $long;
echo "</br>";
echo $speed;
echo "</br>";
echo $date_time;
echo "</br>";
echo $power;
echo "</br>";
echo $door;
echo "</br>";
echo $acc;
echo "</br>";
}else{
    echo "noting";
}
```

Output

```
24.910717
67.073710
0.00
2017-02-22 17:59:00.000
ON
OFF
OFF
```